# Load csv file from S3 to RDS Mysql using AWS data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-data-pipeline

I'm new to AWS, trying to load data from csv file to RDS MySQL using data pipeline "load S3 data into RDS mysql table" template. But getting error "DriverClass not found for database:aurora". Tried setting JDBC uri property point to driver jar in s3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Export pipeline you just created from template and change RDS properties for the following:

```
{
      "*password": "#{*myAuroraPassword}",
      "name": "aurora",
      "connectionString" : "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname",
      "jdbcDriverClass" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      "id": "aurora",
      "type": "JdbcDatabase",
      "username": "#{myUsername}"
}
```